# Unable to call external API (IBM Watson) in Unity C# via HTTP request?

Tags: c#, rest, http, unity-game-engine, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to call IBM Watson's API to perform sentiment analysis from my Unity project, using the WWW library. This is my current code:

```
string uri = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27";

WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
form.AddField ("text", "That%20was%20simply%20magnificent!");
form.AddField ("features", "sentiment");
form.AddField ("Content-Type", "application/json");
var headers = form.headers;
byte[] rawData = form.data;

headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD));

WWW www = new WWW(uri, rawData, headers);
yield return www;
```

where `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD` are my API credentials. However, this code keeps giving me a 415 error. Also, if I change Authorization to Authentication, the error changes to 401.

I've tried making the same request using hurl.it (which works), and I've printed out the authorization header and compared it to what hurl.it constructs given a username and password, and they're the same string - yet the request fails in the project. What am I missing?

Comment: FYI Natural Language Understanding is abstracted in the Watson Unity SDK: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/blob/develop/Scripts/Services/NaturalLanguageUnderstanding/v1/NaturalLanguageUnderstanding.cs

Comment: UnityWebRequest system works for you?

Comment: @jdnichollsc I ended up using the SDK, which worked.

Comment: @Technicolor excellent mate, this is other good option if you want to try https://github.com/proyecto26/RestClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work out for you.

```
private IEnumerator CallNLU()
{
    string uri = "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/analyze?version=2017-02-27";

    var headersDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    headersDict.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headersDict.Add("Accept", "application/json");
    headersDict.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD)));

    string parameters = "{\"text\": \"Hello, welcome to IBM Watson!\", \"features\": {\"keywords\":{\"limit\":50}}}";
    byte[] rawData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(parameters);

    WWW www = new WWW(uri, rawData, headersDict);
    yield return www;
    Debug.Log(www.text);
}
```

Alternatively use the Watson Unity SDK found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk). Here is the [usage](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/unity-sdk/tree/develop/Scripts/Services/NaturalLanguageUnderstanding/v1#analyze).

```
private void Analyze()
{
  if (!_naturalLanguageUnderstanding.Analyze(OnAnalyze, OnFail, <parameters>))
      Log.Debug("ExampleNaturalLanguageUnderstanding.Analyze()", "Failed to get models.");
}

private void OnAnalyze(AnalysisResults resp, Dictionary<string, object> customData)
{
    Log.Debug("ExampleNaturalLanguageUnderstanding.OnAnalyze()", "AnalysisResults: {0}", customData["json"].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the correct media type to the WWWForm like that:

```
form.AddField("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

You should check Watson doc to see which one is the right one, I suppose it'll be Json

Comment: @Technicolor 401 or 415?